# C++ error: ‘string’ has not been declared

Tags: c++, string, header, g++

In my header file I'm getting the

> error: ‘string’ has not been declared

error but at the top of the file I have `#include <string>`, so how can I be getting this error?

Comment: err...source code please :)

Comment: I had the issue that with `#include <string.h>` it doesn't work. There is no error on the include, but it says "error: ‘std::string’ has not been declared". After changing `<string.h>` to `<string>`, it works.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`string` resides in the `std` namespace, you have to use `std::string` or introduce it into the scope via using directives or using declarations.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
std::string var;
```

or

```
using namespace std;
string var;
```

String is in a **std** namespace so you must let your compiler know.

Comment: As long as you do it in the privacy of your own translation units.

Comment: @aschepler: Have my babies

Answer (score 1):

Most of the classes and class templates, and instances of those classes, defined by the Standard Library (like `string` and `cout`) are declared in the `std::` namespace, not in the global [namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace). So, whenever you want to use (say) `string`, the class is *actually* `std::string`.

You can add that namespace prefix *explicitly* every time you use such a class, but that *can* become tedious. In order to help, you can add [`using` *declarations*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations) for those classes you use frequently.

So, in your case, you could add lines like the following, generally somewhere shortly after the corresponding `#include` lines:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::cout; // Added as illustrative examples of other
using std::endl; // ... elements of the Standard Library
```

Or, if you have a compiler that supports the C++17 Standard (or later), you can put more than one class in the same statement:

```cpp
using std::string, std::cout, std::endl; // C++17 or later
```

But, beware of using the generic, "cover-all" `using namespace std;` [*directive*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives) (even though that is actually valid C++ syntax). See: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10871073)

---

For a more general introduction to, and overview of, the Standard Template Library (now, more correctly known as the [C++ Standard Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library)), see [the tag-Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stl/info) for the [stl](/questions/tagged/stl) tag.