# why is string not declared in scope

Tags: c++, boost-thread

I have the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/thread/tss.hpp>

static boost::thread_specific_ptr<string> _tssThreadNameSptr;
```

I get the following error

> g++ -c -I$BOOST_PATH  tssNaming.h
>
> tssNaming.h:7: error: 'string' was not declared in this scope

But I am including string in my `#include`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ error: ‘string’ has not been declared](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890860/c-error-string-has-not-been-declared)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You have to use `std::string` since it's in the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 13):

`string` is in the `std` namespace. You have the following options:

- Write `using namespace std;` after the include and enable all the `std` names: then you can write only `string` on your program.
- Write `using std::string` after the include to enable `std::string`: then you can write only `string` on your program.
- Use `std::string` instead of `string`

Comment: You should use 'using namespace std' or 'using std::string' sparingly and in a bounded scope (for example, inside a function). Never use it in a header, since it would pollute the global namespace with symbols users of your header may not want.

Answer (score 6):

I find that including:

```
using namespace std;
```

To your C++ code saves a lot of time in debugging especially in situations like yours where std:: string is required and also it will help in keeping your code clean.

With this in mind, your code should be:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include <boost/thread/tss.hpp>

static boost::thread_specific_ptr<string> _tssThreadNameSptr;
```